# readLines() function in R treats SUB character as end of file

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have three lines of text in [sub_character.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWeGf.png); the 2nd one is a SUB character. So I run,

`readLines("sub_character.txt")`

and I just get

`[1] "first line"`

It looks like the `readLines()` function interprets the SUB as the end of the file. How do I read the rest of the file?

EDIT: I don't know anything about the SUB character (pasting it here might work: ). But I can offer the following information:

1) I copied it from a string encoded by VimCrypt, and

2) If I install the readr library and run,

`read_file("sub_character.txt")`

I get,

`[1] "first line" "\032"       "third line"`

Which is as good a workaround as any, but I'm still wondering if there's a way to make `readLines()` work.

Comment: What is the “SUB” character? What byte sequence does it correspond to? Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character?

Comment: Anyway, for a file that contains the bytes `666f 6f0a 1a0a 6261 720a` (i.e. `'foo\n\032\nbar'`), `readLines` works as expected; the character is *not* interpreted as the end of the file. Hence my question in the previous comment.